# How do I get comment back links on show up in Google Search Console?

Tags: google, google-search-console, backlinks

How I can get Google to crawl and pay attention to my comment back links?

Whenever I create a back link, it is not showing in Google Webmaster tool.

Comment: The problem is that links you create in comments are not likely to be viewed as high quality by Google.  Instead of helping your site, they may well get your site penalized.  See https://moz.com/ugc/what-is-an-unnatural-link-an-in-depth-look-at-the-google-quality-guidelines

Answer (score 2):

Google Search Console (previously known as Google Webmasters Tools) [may not show all your backlinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en). That doesn't mean they are not being taken into account in the page popularity.

> Not all links to your site may be listed. This is normal. In addition, Google has recently made improvements to how we gather and display link data...

There is nothing you can do to make them appear. You could use another software as [Majestic](https://majestic.com) or [Ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com) to analyze your link profile and check for those backlinks.